# How to use ViewModel in a Razor Pages web app

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a Models class `ProjectDepo` that defines 3 dozen properties.  This has created a table in the db with those fields.  I used Scaffolding to create the iCRUD Razor pages.  All the fields are there correctly and are correctly populating the database table.

I want to create an iCRUD scaffold of only some of those fields/properties and filter the results.  I would use a ViewModel choosing only those specific properties and querying to filter my results to base my scaffolding off of.

When I have created my ViewModel class, how do I specify which Model class these properties are from?  Where can I add a `SQL` statement to filter the results?

I have searched but have not found the right terms.  Everything is about binding the ViewModel to the View, I'm trying to get the data to the ViewModel.

Thank you for any assistance.
chuck

(This is my entire ViewModel class, abbreviated)

```
public class RequestReporterViewModel

{
    //All fields are from ProjectDepo class
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public string OrderingPOCName { get; set; }...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(First, I received notification that someone did NOT like that I chose NOT to capitalize "sql"; that I used parenthesis, had extra spaces and listed the class in my question.  ABSOLUTELY NONE of which made my question easier or more difficult to understand.  The "suggested" and "approved" edits didn't help the question AT ALL.  They didn't provide a solution, didn't make the question clearer - they ONLY made the question meet the suggesters format.)
(//end of rant)

Anyways, this question can be closed as I was looking for a way to handle this ViewModel WITHOUT creating a Controller.

I'll keep searching for an answer using different search criteria elsewhere.

thank you to anyone that took the time to read my question, it is appreciated.

chuck

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Overflow has a problem with this, Chuck. Many contributors seem to believe they are 'most elite', and instead of providing advice on the question that is actually being asked, they provide unhelpful comments about your rationale, design pattern or code etc. It can be a very unwelcoming place at times.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to map binded properties fron view to model you can use [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org), AutoMapper is best practice for this state.

for your  example :

```
Mapper.Map(RequestReporter, RequestReporterViewModel, typeof(RequestReporter), typeof(RequestReporterViewModel));
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide an answer.  I was looking to where I should write the sql that only includes a couple of the fields of the entire model.